# how to set URL (admin instead of backend/web) in yii2 advanced application

Tags: yii2

I am facing a grate problem in my project.
When i browse url with my project name than it's show folders, but i don't want to show those folder i want to show direct my web site, like 'localhost/mywebsite/admin'.

I also try to solve this problem to add my backend/config/main.php file

```
'urlManager' => [
'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
'showScriptName' => 'false'
],
```

but it does not work.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Read this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md#configuring-web-servers-

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mean that. I mean In YII 2.0 advanced application, how to configure or customize URL for backend application

Answer (score 0):

Customize URL:

```
   'urlManager' => [
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'enableStrictParsing' => true,          
                'rules' => [
                    '<_c:[\w\-]+>' => '<_c>/index',
                    '<_c:[\w\-]+>/<_a:[\w\-]+>' => '<_c>/<_a>',
                    '<_c:[\w\-]+>/<_a:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<_c>/<_a>',
                ],
            ],
```

In `apache.conf` input `DocumentRoot /var/www/backend/web`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but when i browse localhost/myprojectname/admin than show all folders in projects and if i select backend/web than show not found error. Please give me some another solution. Thanks.